# How to wait until webBrowser1 completey loads after webBrowser1 click or submit event fired

Tags: c#, browser, load, click, submit

there are countless of examples how to wait until page fully loads after navigate event

but there are not even a single example how to wait until submit of click event fired next page fully loads

how can i achive this

what i want is after webBrowser1 click or submit (form) event fired how to wait next page (after click or submit event it goes another page) fully loads

thank you

Comment: thanks for reminding me now i am marking them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event be what you are looking for?

Here's the example given on the documentation page. It prints the page as soon as the document has been fully loaded. You can modify it for your needs.

```
private void PrintHelpPage()
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"\\myshare\help.html");
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: how can i use documentcompleted ?

Comment: i already found this example. but how is this going to help me ? i have a loop which open pages and click or submit forms automaticly. after this event it goes next page. but i have to write a function which will wait until fired event completes (form submit or click button)